# 'Permission denied' intentando correr un script de JMeter desde Jenkins en linux

Tags: linux, jenkins, jmeter

estoy teniendo un problema al intentar correr un script de JMeter desde un job de Jenkins. Tengo integrado un proyecto simple de GitHub a jenkins, en el que solo tengo un archivo .jmx(script de JMeter). Jenkins hace el pull, trae todo bien pero cuando intenta acceder a la carpeta de JMeter me tira error de 'Permission denied'. Intenté varias cosas y la verdad que no puedo hacer andar.
Este es el mensaje de error;

```
+ /var/jenkins_home/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin -n -t /var/jenkins_home/workspace/JMeterTest/JMeter_Script_Plugins.jmx -l /var/jenkins_home/workspace/JMeterTest/JMeter_Script_Plugins-19.jtl -Jthreads=10 -Jrampup=10 -Jduration=120 -R localhost:8080 -e -o /var/jenkins_home/workspace/JMeterTest/19
/tmp/jenkins11953508967479940222.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Tengo este comando en el shell para que acceda a esos directorios;

```
EXECUTE SHELL
$JENKINS_HOME/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin -n -t $WORKSPACE/JMeter_Script_Plugins.jmx -l $WORKSPACE/JMeter_Script_Plugins-$BUILD_NUMBER.jtl -Jthreads=$Threads -Jrampup=$RampUp -Jduration=$Duration -R $RemoteEngine -e -o $WORKSPACE/$BUILD_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es más que seguro que `/var/jenkins_home/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin` es un directorio así que no estás llamando un script. Debe ser algo así como

```
/var/jenkins_home/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/algun_script_o_binario
```

Comment: Efectivamente era esto. Luego del bin escribí /jmeter.sh (el ejecutable) y anduvo todo a la perfección. Muchas gracias!